# change the sound volume of a live stream

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, audio

I have something like this:

```
private var myVideo:Video;
public var videoDisplay:UIComponent;
...
videoDisplay.addChild(myVideo);
...
nsPlay = new NetStream(nc);
nsPlay.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, nsPlayOnStatus);
nsPlay.bufferTime = 0;
nsPlay.play(pro);
myVideo.attachNetStream(nsPlay);
```

anybody knows how can I change the volume of this stream, I would like to bind the volume to a slider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [NetStream::SoundTransform](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html#soundTransform) property.

```
nsPlay.soundTransform.volume = slider.value;
```

To bind the value of slider to the volume:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(nsPlay.soundTransform, "volume", slider, "value");
```

Set the slider range as 0 to 1

Answer (score 3):

Use the property [soundTransform](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_fr/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/SoundTransform.html) of the [NetStream](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html#soundTransform) Object:

```
var st:SoundTransform=nsPlay.soundTransform;
st.volume=0.5; // 50% volume
nsPlay.soundTransform=st;
```